# Are there any football stadiums where you can stay overnight?

Tags: accommodation, hotels, football

This is probably one for the football fans! I know that many football stadiums offer tours around, generally during the day. Quite a few offer conference facilities, and I can attest that a coffee break between sessions is a lot more refreshing when you can go to to sit outside on the terraces!

For the next step on from that - are there any stadiums where you can stay overnight?

Comment: football[UK] or football[US]?

Comment: @Jonas don't forget about Aussie Rules Football too! Perhaps it doesn't matter, but Football (aka Soccer) was what I'd had in mind

Comment: Never knew that Aussies would have their own version, though I know that Canadian Football is different from American Football as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is at least one - the [Hilton DoubleTree Milton Keynes](http://doubletree3.hilton.com/en/hotels/united-kingdom/doubletree-by-hilton-hotel-milton-keynes-LTNDTDI/index.html) is located *in* the West stand of the 32,000-seat Stadium MK! (Home to the MKDONS)

Several of the room types feature views out over the pitch (you'd want the ones saying "With View" in the booking list), and the restaurant/bar has views out of the pitch.

The only downside is that the executive rooms are generally unavailable on match days, as they're used for hospitality, and someone on FT mentioned that not all of the fitness facilities are available on match days as apparently they get used by the teams!

The hotel is also only a short distance from [Bletchley Park](http://www.bletchleypark.org.uk/), which is a must-visit for any crypto/spy/code-breaking/computer/history geek, and you can often get some stunningly good advanced-purchase deals at the hotel for weekend stays :)

Comment: There are a few photos on the hotel's website showing it, though I may have to get a few to decorate the answer with when I'm there in a few weeks!

Answer (score 0):

Reading FC Madejeski stadium also has the http://www.millenniumhotels.co.uk/millenniumreading/ as part of the same complex.

Comment: Looks from the map and description like the hotel is in another building next to the stadium, rather than actually being part of it